# Axios Get does recognize the db collection balances but Put or Post or Patch does not

Tags: axios, get, put

so I have a fullstack React App, this type of code I have data on db. collection that I can access by Axios Get, but this data is not accessible by Put to update it, Its a balance credit account that I what every time a client buy something the admin accepted the order, this Balance would be decreased by that sum, I will post some pictures so anyone could understand what I'm trying to explain, [this is my collection on my db mongo compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yT8R.jpg)[the Axios get works perfecty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSu1K.jpg) [Axios get Result consol.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTq4E.jpg) [Axios put that doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn8ZK.jpg) [result of Axios Put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh1B4.jpg).

How to resolve this?

I was Expecting Put Request to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your screenshots were incomplete, it seems that `_id` is not defined in the function body. You seem to be forgetting to pass `_id` into the function as a parameter.